# Why transition:opacity affects on padding in % (in -webkit- browsers)

Tags: html, css

Some strange behaviour was noticed in -webkit- browsers. If padding is given in "%" and we apply transition:opacity effect on children, the children is affected at the and of the action. If padding is in px (or em) everything is ok. The problem is only in -webkit-  browsers.
HTML

```
<div class="red">
    <div class="blue">
        padding in %
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="red1">
    <div class="blue">
        padding in px
    </div>    
</div>
```

Css

```
.red{
    background-color: red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding: 5%;
}
.red1{
    background-color: red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
    height:100px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.blue:hover{
    opacity:0.5;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

And example: http://jsfiddle.net/48jUg/3/

P.S. The problem is seems to appear when browser window's wide is between 1050 and 1200 px

Comment: Both div works on Chrome. No Issues here.

Comment: @Surjith SM the problem is seems to  appear when browser window's wide is between 1050 and 1200 px

Comment: Moving it to a comment: Not related to this, but the transition better be applied on `.blue` not on `.blue:hover`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/48jUg/3/ The percent or pixel values don't matter.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, your jsfiddle is working perfectly for me (within your suggested window width)

Comment: Webkit has horrible rendering issues. This kind of thing doesn't surprise me any more.

Comment: @DBS  here is video how it works. http://screencast.com/t/rUhoriD4yx . But the problem appears also on the second div. Possibly it just problem's of rendering and there is nothing can be done with this problem?

Comment: @abhitalks , sure, thanks, i've updated the link, but it doesn't solve the problem